# Multiple producers accessing multiple shared queues by checking for space two times

Tags: c++, pthreads, producer-consumer

I request a review on the way multiple producers and consumers access multiple shared queues.

What I have done here requires the threads to check for the space in queues minimum two times. Can it be made better someway?

Of course, I can create another queue where these queues will be kept in the decreasing order w.r.t space. That way the check will be eliminated since only those queues which have some space will be on that queue.

**My question is - Is all this really worth the effort? Will it really save a significant time as compared to the current method?**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  conditionVariable = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int numberOfActiveProducers;
int numberOfActiveConsumers;

QList <int> sharedQueueA;
QList <int> sharedQueueB;

/*
 * Shared queues are supposed to be shared among four threads. Two producer, and two consumer threads.
 * Producer threads will put the 1's in it, and Consumer threads will remove the 1's.
 * Assumption: `sharedQueue` can contain only 10 elements at a time.
 */

int sizeOfSharedQueue;

void checkForSpaceAndPush (QList <int> & argList, int listId, pthread_t argTId)
{
    if (argList.length () < 10)
    {
        std::cerr << "\nQueue " << listId << ", First check by Producer: " << argTId;
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);
        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", Locked by Producer: " << argTId;

        if (argList.length () < 10)
        {
            argList.push_back (1); std::cerr << "\nPushed by Producer " << argTId << ": " << "Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "\nProducer " << argTId << ". Queue " << listId << " is full. Length of queue is: " << argList.length ();
            pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariable, &mutexVariable);
        }

        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", UnLocked by Producer: " << argTId;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
    }
}

void checkForSpaceAndPop (QList <int> & argList, int listId, pthread_t argTId)
{
    if (argList.length () > 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "\nQueue " << listId << ", First check by Consumer: " << argTId;
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);
        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", Locked by Consumer: " << argTId;

        if (argList.length () > 0)
        {
            argList.pop_front (); std::cerr << "\nRemoved by Consumer: " << argTId << ", Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_signal (&conditionVariable); std::cerr << "\nSignal issued by Consumer: " << argTId << ", Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
        }

        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", UnLocked by Consumer: " << argTId;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
    }
}

//  This function is run by the `Producer` threads.
void *producerThreadFunction (void *arg)
{
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self(); std::cerr << "\nProducers: " << tId; std::cerr.flush();
        checkForSpaceAndPush (sharedQueueA, 1, tId);
        checkForSpaceAndPush (sharedQueueB, 2, tId);
    }

    return NULL;
}

//  This function is run by the `Consumer` threads.
void *consumerThreadFunction (void *arg)
{
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self (); std::cerr << "\nConsumer: " << tId; std::cerr.flush();
        checkForSpaceAndPop (sharedQueueA, 1, tId);
        checkForSpaceAndPop (sharedQueueB, 2, tId);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    numberOfActiveProducers = 2;
    numberOfActiveConsumers = 2;
    sizeOfSharedQueue       = 10;

    // Producer threads creation
    pthread_t producerA;
    pthread_t producerB;

    if (pthread_create (&producerA, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&producerB, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Consumer threads creation
    pthread_t consumerA;
    pthread_t consumerB;

    if (pthread_create (&consumerA, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&consumerB, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Joining every thread
    if (pthread_join (producerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (producerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    return a.exec ();
}
```

Comment: "Will it really save a significant time as compared to the current method?" - what are you comparing against what? An explanation of the problem you're trying to solve would help - as it is, it's hard to understand why you'd want multiple queues at all and why you're trying to solve it like this. (There's also a lot of noise in what you posted - variables that are only set, never read, QApplication  stuff that is irrelevant, lots and lots of duplicated cod.e)

Comment: @Mat `what are you comparing against what?` comparing the way I have already done with the way I proposed in the question.  It is about the way threads are accessing the shared queues. -- `it's hard to understand why you'd want multiple queues at all` That is the producer consumer problem. There are multiple  producers and consumers which want to access multiple queues. QApplication is required because I wrote this code in QtCreator. You can ignore that stuff.  --- `lots and lots of duplicated cod.e` I don't know if it is valid to create a new func. for duplicate code in the "threads" program.

Comment: Since you're programming in C++, your code could be more portable and more streamlined if you used `std::thread` instead of pthreads.

Comment: @Edward: I agree with you should use `std::thread`. But more portable I question. pthreads has been around a long time and been ported to nearly everything. It will be a while before the C++ compiler catches up.

Comment: There is nothing C++ like about this code. This is written as C with a couple of classes thrown in. But basically it is C in both style and usage.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

You should be using std::thread and family rather than pthread. The main reason is that these `objects` are exception aware and will do the correct thing when being destroyed.

Moving on assuming we are talking about pthreads.
Secondly you don't use RAII enough. As objects you create via pthread are not cleaned up correctly in all situations and as a result your application is not well defined.

pthreads is a **`C`** library. As a result all it knows about is `C` stuff (this includes functions). Passing C++ stuff to a C library is undefined. So the callback functions you use in `pthread_create()` need to be declared as C functions otherwise there is no guarantee they will work correctly. To declare them as `C` functions you need to `extern "C"`

Your design relies on global objects. This is always a red flag. All this queue handling shenanigans should be done inside a class to protect the the queues from some other programmer coming along and using them in some other manner than is expected by your code. You can then declare a single object in the main function and pass it around as a parameter (so you don't get global state that can be accidentally mutated from somewhere else).

### Design

I am not clear what you are trying to do.
The code does not do what the description above says.

> What I have done here requires the threads to check for the space in queues minimum two times. Can it be made better someway?

What it does do is try and queue an item twice then in a tight loop try and queue it again. I assume you only want an item queue once in one of the lists. Thats not what is happening.

Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to achieve (the final result/not what the code is trying to do). Then we can provide help in achieving that.

### Code Review.

Global state bad.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  conditionVariable = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int numberOfActiveProducers;
int numberOfActiveConsumers;

QList <int> sharedQueueA;
QList <int> sharedQueueB;
//   ^   This space is weird and disconcerting. 
//       The whole thing is the type keep it as a single entity.
```

Wrap these in a class. Then declare one variable in `main()` that you pass as a parameter to anybody that needs it. Then you can control construction and destruction via scope.

Good comment.

```
/*
 * Shared queues are supposed to be shared among four threads. Two producer, and two consumer threads.
 * Producer threads will put the 1's in it, and Consumer threads will remove the 1's.
 * Assumption: `sharedQueue` can contain only 10 elements at a time.
 */
```

In `checkForSpaceAndPush()` and `checkForSpaceAndPop()` this is not the normal may to use a condition variable. Currently your code goes into a hyper aggressive spin if `argList.length() >= 10` (checkForSpaceAndPush) which will melt your CPU from the logic board.

It normally looks like this:

```
     mutex.lock()
     while(<bad condition>) {
         conditionVariable.wait(mutex);
     }
     <Do work here>
     mutex.unlock();
```

Because you are using these two functions as callbacks from the `C` `pthread` library they need to be declared as `C` functions.

```
extern "C" void void *consumerThreadFunction (void *arg);
extern "C" void *producerThreadFunction (void *arg);
```

If this has not way to exit. Your join() will wait forever.

```
    while (1)
```

You should have some exit criteria so the thread can terminate naturally. PS. allowing an exception to propagate passed the exit of thread is not defined (but usually causes program termination).

Why do you need to get the thread id every iteration. You could just get it once before the loop starts.

```
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self(); std::cerr << "\nProducers: " << tId; std::cerr.flush();
```

At this point you have created a thread. But if you fail to create the second thread you exit the program without cleaning up the resources of the first thread. A bit of RAII here would definitely help.

```
    if (pthread_create (&producerB, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer B\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

You start your application after all the work has been done!

```
    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    return a.exec ();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed write up. I will be addressing your points in separate comments.

Comment: You said: `You should be using std::thread and family rather than pthread. The main reason is that these objects are exception aware and will do the correct thing when being destroyed.` Thanks for the information, but that is the main reason I won't be in near future using std or boost threads. My purpose is to "learn". If std will do all good in background then I won't know and thus learn anything about doing it proper.

Comment: you said `What it does do is try and queue an item twice then in a tight loop try and queue it again.` I did not understand this point at all. In the function `checkForSpaceAndPush` I have first checked the queue's length to find some empty space with this statement: `if (argList.length () < 10)` then, again I am trying to confirm the space availability inside the lock. What's wrong there? What do you mean by "queue an item"? I just intend to check for space availability.

Comment: You said: `Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to achieve`. I'll try again - In the normal producer consumer problem, there is one producer, one consumer, and one shared queue. Here I have made two of each of them. That's all, and I want them to push and pop data in a thread safe way.

Comment: You said: `Currently your code goes into a hyper aggressive spin if argList.length() >= 10` Didn't understand at all. The check in `checkForSpaceAndPush` is this: `if (argList.length () < 10)` If the len is greater than 10, `pthread_cond_wait` will put the code in "doing nothing" mode till a signal is received from the consumer. If that isn't the way it should used, then what is the purpose of `pthread_cond_wait`? Isn't that for sleeping? Whatever, well, it seems I am missing some point. Please explain in a layman language.

Comment: `If std will do all good in background then I won't know and thus learn anything about doing it proper`. Thats the wrong way to think about it. The `std::thread` is the proper way to do it. You will not learn anything particularly useful using `pthreads`.

Comment: `, there is one producer, one consumer`. This is wrong. The producer consumer problem usually assumes multiple of both.

Comment: `if (argList.length () < 10)` if the length == 10 then you don't enter the loop. You exit the function. The function is immediately called again and the processes repeats. Since you have not yielded the thread (because you did not call `wait()` on the condition variable) on a lot of systems this will lock up. Even in multiple cpu systems you can easily starve the other threads because this thread always gets to re-lock the mutex.